# Statistical term for distribution spanning zero

Tags: terminology

Is there a statistical word for a data distribution that spans zero?  For instance, 'sentiment' data distributions can hypothetically range from negative to positive.  The value distributions might be normal or skewed or whatever.  Does 'bipolar' apply?  I've not seen it used in this context.  And 'bimodal' isn't right as the data could be unimodal in nature.  Thoughts?

Comment: What do you mean by `spanning zero`?

Comment: For example `rnorm(100, mean = 0)`

Comment: So spanning zero means having a mean equal to 0?? Do you mean including zero? Something else?

Comment: I don't know, but maybe a term you may find useful is [support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution#Basic_terms) which is the *set of values that can be assumed with non-zero probability by the random variable*. @user2974951 I suppose that by "spans 0" the OP means distribution that, like the Normal, support from negative to positve values including zero (as opposed to e.g. the Poisson).

Comment: I don't think the idea is that the mean is zero. I don't think there is a simple term, although as @dariober flags you can talk about the support, or sometimes the domain, or sometimes the range of possible values.

Comment: Sometimes we emphasize that values can be positive or negative (or zero, if that is true and important) whenever that is not obvious or it bites in a way that may not be obvious.  "Obvious" depends on what readers should know. The situation that arises most often in my experience is such a variable with a skewed distribution and/or one with outliers that you are considering for transformation. In this case log or root transformations are not feasible. But I'll not turn this into a discussion of what you can or can't do with such variables when the question at present is about terminology.

Comment: These are useful comments. It sounds like statisticians mostly refer to 'positive' or 'negative' distributions to distinguish these, and otherwise it is either left unstated or described in more verbose terms. Slightly surprising though given the mixed case is mathematically unique - e.g. you can't flip the sign to calculate its geometric mean as you can with a negative distribution. If anyone would like to pull this together as an answer they're welcome to the tick.

Comment: I am not a statistician, but as a dirty-handed scientist of sorts I would regard it as our responsibility to know our data. It is usually well known whether a variable is  or can be variously positive; positive or zero; positive or zero or negative; and so on. But there can be surprises.

Comment: I once had a practical in which a major lesson was take logarithms! This went down well with the students, or so it seemed, but the following week some were over-zealous and took logarithms of mean temperatures in Celsius. I had a lot of explaining to do about that being a poor choice for several reasons, not least the occurrence of several stations with negative means.  But your case of sentiment seems one in which a definition in terms of positive and negative is there for all to see.

Comment: @dariober You were there first, so why not have a go? Feel free to take any of my comments that might help.